# How can I specify an element's width as the most it can be without causing a newline break?

Tags: html, css, width, overflow

I'm quite new to CSS. I'd like to display a long line of text overflowing with ellipses. [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrtmdnke/) demonstrates a working example.

However, note that if you extend the window, the text remains limited at 100px (due to the `max-width: 100px`) attribute. If I remove the max-width attribute, though, the text [never shrinks](https://jsfiddle.net/Lysoecxy/):

[image]

I'd like the text to extend as much as possible without causing a line-break. i.e. this is how it should look for the various window widths:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick.. you can use `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;` then add `margin-right: 75px;` so that the text will not overlap the button.

```
.one-line-only {
    font-family: monospace;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 75px; /*(you can set the value depends on your needs)*/
}
```

then add this css on your button, then add `margin-top: -20px;` to inline the button.

```
.b{
    margin-top: -20px; /*(you can set the value depends on your needs)*/
    float:right;
}
```

---

```
<span class="one-line-only"> Stuff to the left ----  Thisisareallylongthingwhichshouldbestoppedatsomepointforsure</span>
<button class='b'>Stuff right</button>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yt43gc7o/3/)**